# function A is undefined when being called by function B defined in an angular service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have trouble with the following code in my service:

```
angular.module('my_proj').factory('artistService',
    function($injector, $ionicListDelegate, $rootScope, $state,
         $stateParams, $timeout, $translate, SomeStore,
         appConstants, appService, coreService, moment, loginService) {
    return {
            goToMedia: function(artistId, state) {
                var self = this;

                SomeStore.findByPk(artistId, {}, function(reminder) {

                // works
                $injector.get('artistService').applyMusicFilter(reminder);

                // throws "applyMusicFilter is not a function"
                self.applyMusicFilter(reminder);
           }
    }
}
```

I suspect it's an issue with the order my code is run by the interpreter. Calling the same function with the $injector, works, but calling it directly by using self as a reference to this doesn't.

Can anyone tell me, what's the problem here and what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it to work, is to use a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function):

```
app.factory('artistService', function($injector, $ionicListDelegate,
         $rootScope, $state, loginService) {
    return {
        applyMusicFilter: applyMusicFilter,
        goToMedia: function(artistId, state) {
            //Invoke hoisted function
            applyMusicFilter("whatever");
        }
    };
    //Function declaration
    function applyMusicFilter(reminder) {
        console.log(reminder)
    }
})
```

In JavaScript, function definitions are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). You can use the function before you declared it.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `self` refers to the `goToMedia` function which do not have the definition for `applyMusicFilter` because of which you got undefined error.

`$injector` method worked because it returns the object created by the factory which contains all the method definitions.